# Normalizing singularities in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, boundary-conditions

I've tried to create the following example. Suppose that I have the differential equation:

$$
U''(x) = \frac{U'(x) - U(x)}{x},
$$

which I know 1 boundary condition and know that this function should behave normal at the origin. Thus, I would assume that to keep the function normal it should be true that:

$$
U'(0) = U(0),
$$

with say my 1 boundary condition is:

$$
U(1) = 10,
$$

or something of the sort. I would have then expected I could solve this differential equation with:

```
soln = NDSolve[{U''[x] == (U'[x] - U[x])/x, U'[0] == U[0], 
   U[10] == 10}, 
  U, 
  {x, 0, 1},
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
         "StartingInitialConditions" -> {U[0] == 1}}]
```

however, this immediately gives an infinite expression. Looking at the trace it seems that it does not consider that the numerator is $+1-1$ at all:

```
(-1. + 1.)/0.
Message[Power::infy, 1/0.]
```

Any thoughts on how to analyze such a differential equation? Any response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the deq is singular at zero, the easiest workaround is to start the solution a little above zero.

Assign an small value

```
\[Epsilon] = 10^-10

soln = NDSolve[{U''[x] == (U'[x] - U[x])/x, U[\[Epsilon]] == 1, 
    U[1] == 10}, U[x], {x, \[Epsilon], 1}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {U'[\[Epsilon]] == 1}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 25] // Flatten
```

I raised the working precision a little to get rid of some warnings about precision.

```
U[x_] = U[x] /. soln
```

This particular problem can also be solved analytically:

```
sol = DSolve[{deq, u'[0] == u[0], u[0] == 1, u[1] == 10}, 
   u[x], {x, 0, 1}] // Flatten

u[x_] = u[x] /. sol
```

Check

```
Limit[u'[x] - u[x], x -> 0]
(*  0  *)

u[1]
(*  10  *)

Limit[u[x], x -> 0]
(*  1  *)
```

Mathematica gets infinity for `x = 0`, but taking the limit yields correct values.

Plot the numeric and symbolic solutions.

```
Plot[{U[x], u[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

And they overlay.

Answer (score 3):

The ODE may be solved symbolically with

```
uFN = DSolveValue[{U''[x] == (U'[x] - U[x])/x}, U, {x, 0, 2}]

(* Function[{x}, 2 x (BesselJ[2, 2 Sqrt[x]] C[1] - BesselY[2, 2 Sqrt[x]] C[2])]  *)
```

The singularity enforces the desired "boundary condition" at `x == 0` on the whole solution space:

```
Limit[uFN'[x] - uFN[x], x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
(*  0  *)
```

The BC at `x == 10` reduces the dimension of the solution space by 1:

```
uFN10 = DSolveValue[{U''[x] == (U'[x] - U[x])/x, U[1] == 10}, 
  U, {x, 0, 2}]
(*
Function[{x}, 
 2 x (BesselJ[2, 2 Sqrt[x]] C[1] + 
   (BesselY[2, 2 Sqrt[x]] (5 - BesselJ[2, 2] C[1]))/BesselY[2, 2])]
*)

Plot[Table[uFN10[x] /. C[1] -> c, {c, 0, 10, 2}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, to see the family of solutions with `NDSolve`, just use an IVP at `U[10] == 10` (or `u[1] == 10` as above), with a varying value for `U'[10]`. This make an nice, suggestive image: `ListLinePlot@Table[NDSolveValue[{U''[x] == (U'[x] - U[x])/x, U'[10] == m, U[10] == 10}, U, {x, 0 + $MachineEpsilon, 25}], {m, -3, 3}]`

Answer (score 1):

Start NDSolve at a slightly negative x with m as parameter for `U'[1] == m` , and you have no problems at x == 0. Determine the corresponding m at x==0 for U[m][0]== "anyValue".

As @MichaelE2 says, "The singularity enforces the desired "boundary condition" at x == 0"

```
sol = Solve[U''[x] == (U'[x] - U[x])/x, U[x]]
sol /. x -> 0
(*   {{U[0] -> Derivative[1][U][0]}}   *)

Usol[m_?NumericQ] := 
U /. First@
NDSolve[{U''[x] == (U'[x] - U[x])/x, U'[1] == m, U[1] == 10}, 
U, {x, -10^-14, 3/2}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[Usol[m][x], {m, -50, 50, 11/3}]], {x, 0, 1.5}]
```

[image]

```
Max@Abs@Table[Usol[m][0] - Usol[m]'[0], {m, -50, 50, 11/3}]
(*   2.30926*10^-13   *)

m1 = m /. FindRoot[Evaluate[Usol[m][0] == 1], {m, 3}]
(*   13.5113   *)

m1000 = m /. FindRoot[Evaluate[Usol[m][0] == 1000], {m, 3}]
(*   -2817.85   *)

Plot[Evaluate[Usol[m1000][x]], {x, 0, 1}]
```